# Android Bumblebee NavController drawer menu corrupted

Tags: kotlin, navigation-drawer

After upgrade do Android Studio Bumblebee and Graddle 7.2 (i belive) and navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0-alpha01 my navigation component went crazy.

When I open a fragment from option menu it works fine, but when I open fragment from drawer then it somehow "overrides" bottom menu and I cannot open fragment from bottom menu on which I opened fragment from drawer. To "unlock" bottom menu I have to use back arrow, and only after that the fragment from bottom menu can be reopened. I don't have any particular order of fragments in nav_graph. Any fragment can be opened in any order. I want to make bottom menu to workd such way that I can always open 1 of 4 main fragments no matter what other fragment is currently opened - without need of clicking "back".

I have bottom, drawer and options navigation. I have 4 main fragments that are accesible from bottom menu. All other fragments are accesible from options or drawer and all fragments have global action in nav_graph that includes:

```
app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

I want always go to homeFragment inclusive from any other fragment despite of the order of opening fragments
My code:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

// List of fragments without 'back arrow' - accesible from bottom menu
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
    setOf(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.settingsFragment, R.id.logFragment, R.id.mapFragment),
    bind.drawerLayout
)

setSupportActionBar(bind.toolbar)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
bind.bottomNav.setupWithNavController(navController)
bind.drawerView.setupWithNavController(navController)

// Drawer menu
val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.drawerView)

// Click on item in navigation drawer
navView.menu.findItem(R.id.drawerItemOpen).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    navController.navigate(R.id.listFragment)
    bind.drawerLayout.close()
    true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean { return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp() }
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean { menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu) return true }
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean { return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) }
```

Is something wrong with this code ?
Thank you

Comment: I found this answer informative. [Version 2.4 uses multiple back stacks ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71566840/9325170)

Answer (score 0):

I revert to version 2.3.0

```
androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0
androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
```

It seems that newer version 2.4.0 works differently.

I also changed a way of calling navigate action from:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.listFragment)
```

to

```
navController.navigate(PlanListFragmentDirections.actionGlobalPlanListFragment())
```