# Fragment navigation and menu. How to remove latest fragment? Check description

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-menu, android-navigation

I was incapable of finding an answer for the following context:

Let's say we have a menu and a nav graph instanced in the main activity. We have 3 fragment: Home, ItemList and Settings. We add another fragment called HourPreference.
Take the next flow: I press on the bottom menu on the Settings item which takes me on the SettingsFragment. Then we press a button to take us to the HourPreferenceFragment using `findNavController().navigate(SettingsFragmentDirections.actionNavigationNotificationsToNavigationHourPreference())`. We are on HourPreferenceFragment. IF we press back then it takes us to SettingsFragment. But IF we press on the home item from the bottom menu, then it takes us on that Fragment and when we press on the bottom menu on the Settings item then it directions us to the HourPreferenceFragment and not the SettingsFragment. Code snippets down below. How can we get to the SettingsFragment when we go along with this flow? I appreciate any answer whether you provide me a link to another post, I was just unable to find anything after a couple hours

Briefly:

The behaviour is: Press settings icon (display SettingsFragment) -> Press hour preference (display HourPreferenceFragment)-> press home icon (display HomeFragment) -> press settings icon and it takes me to HourPreference Fragment BUT I want it to take me to the SettingsFragment!

(MainActivity.onCreate):

```
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.navigation_home,
            R.id.navigation_items_list,
            R.id.navigation_settings
        )
    )

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

//also

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
          return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

(activity_main.xml)

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

Also in the mobile_navigation.xml graph:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
    android:name="com.example.xpiry1.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_settings"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >

    <action
                android:id="@+id/action_navigation_notifications_to_navigation_hour_preference"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_hour_preference"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_settings" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_hour_preference"
    android:name="com.example.xpiry1.ui.settings.preferences.HourPreferenceFragment"
    android:label="Hour Preferences"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hour_preference">
    </fragment>
```

(SettingsFragment)

```
 binding.hourPreference.root.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(SettingsFragmentDirections.actionNavigationNotificationsToNavigationHourPreference())
```

Comment: Try to remove this line : `app:popUpTo="@id/navigation_settings"`. I think that the last visited destination remain in the backstack, so if you switch  back to the settings it shows the fragment on the top, which is `HourPreferenceFragment.`

Comment: @VítKapitola It doesn't work, and, also, the behaviour is: Press settings icon -> Press hour preference -> press home icon -> press settings icon and it takes me to HourPreference Fragment BUT I want it to take me to the SettingsFragment

Comment: I have implemented somethink silimilar, all is the same except this. In overriden method `onSupportNavigateUp()` I am supplying my appBarConfiguration. Try to modify `return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()` with `return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)`. Variable `appBarConfiguration` can be a property of the Activity.

Comment: @VítKapitola changed as you said but is doesn't work. I have the same flow as described in the problem. It takes me to HourFragment instead of SettingsFragment

Comment: Ok, it can by also a version incompability of fragments and Navigation components. Which version of navigation and fragment do you use?

Comment: @VítKapitola 
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.1'

Comment: I meant `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1"` there should be a problem when lower than 1.3.6 for example. No more ideas for now.

Comment: @VítKapitola you were right! It was about the version of the fragment. I downgraded to 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5' and it works as desired

Comment: I guessed a version incompability between navigation lib and fragment lib but it was a new navigations library behaviour with backstacks. Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the core issue for this problem. The detailed explanation lies in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71566840/12441683).

For the moment, Is solved it by downgrading the the fragment dependency from 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.1'
to
**'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'**
and now everything works fine.